# Does numbering have shortcut?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I would like to ask a question on Word shortcuts.

For bullets list, I know there is a shortcut CTRL + SHIFT + L, but for numbering, does there exist a shortcut?

Comment: "for numbering, does there exist a shortcut?" No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign your own shortcut.

Here is how:

Menu: File --> Options --> Customize Ribbon --> Keyboard-shortcuts [at the very bottom of the dialogue!]: Customize

Select from "Categories" the "Home Tab", then select from "Commands" the "Numbering Gallery". Assign a key shortcut to it (e.g. Alt+n+u, or whatever you like and is not in use for other things).

[image]

That's it. You have your own shortcut for assigning auto-numbering to paragraphs. To use it, put the cursor somewhere in the paragraph you want to get numbered (or mark multiple paragraphs), and type your shortcut (while pressing down the Alt key).

(By the way, I hate auto-numbering. But if you like it...)

Comment: Is auto numbering do some bugs?

Comment: @Mohamed Magdy  Well, at least in my style of writing (and I am producing a lot of documents every day in Word) the automatic numbering is more a nuisance than a help. But it depends, of course, fully on what you are doing and what are your habits. I suppose the function is there because people do use it.